# Trouble connecting to endpoint with TcpClient where port > 8000

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, port, tcpclient

We have some legacy c++ applications that can connect to these port to other servers, however, when we create (rather try to create) a connection using tcpclient we get the "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" for the port.  When we change the port to something like 8000, it works fine but we cant leave it like this as we have legacy apps working of those ports.

Should I not be using TcpClient for this, is there another way still using TcpClient?  Thanks

Here is sample code:

```
 const int port = 80011;
 client.Connect(addressTxt.Text, port);
```

using a valid ip address and a valid port I get a connection, using port 80011 or any port greater an exception is thrown (any port above 65536 is throwing this exception).

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, ports can only be in the range of 0-65535. You can not use a port number that wouldn't fit to a 16-bit number.

For more details see the TCP header format: http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section4/8.htm